# Possible to publish ClickOnce DIRECTLY to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, clickonce, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to be able to have the ClickOnce publishing push it to an Azure blob storage container?

If not, is this something that is planned for the future?

---

I have read the articles about how to publish the ClickOnce deployment and then copy the files up to Azure Blob storage (like: [How to deploy
ClickOnce to Azure](http://kazinadudvari.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/how-to-deploy-clickonce-applications-to-windows-azure/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Clickonce process is to package your application in a way which is deployed from a location either on internet or local. Where the final click once package is stored is not maintained by ClickOnce process. I do not know if there is a future plan about it however I don't think there is a need for click once to make Azure blob store dependent. It can be done by customization of build process to package the clickonce content and upload to Azure Blob storage by providing proper credentials.

As you can use [MSBUILD to generate Clickonce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) package you can customize this process further more to upload these clickonce file to Azure Blob storage by writing a very small command line application and automating after MSBUILD finished creating the clickonce package. In this [Forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuresecurity/thread/0aad6995-1eed-4f7d-8538-2ccfecc1f909) the user have some code snippet to build the cmd line app to upload the package. You sure can come up with something similar to meet your requirement.